# Some PDF readers not printing tax form in color

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-reader

I want to print the [Massachusetts resident income tax return form](https://www.mass.gov/files/documents/2018/02/07/dor-2017-inc-form-1.pdf) which has both black and red letters. When I print this document with Adobe Reader or Foxit, everything is black and white (no color). When I print exactly the same document with Sumatra PDF, it prints correctly with red letters. Why would Sumatra PDF print the document correctly, but the other two do not? Note that I use both Foxit and Adobe Reader to print color documents all the time. It is only the tax form that seems to have a problem.

Comment: Interesting that the official Adobe Reader doesn't print this official state document correctly - I would think that this would be the default testing scenario when Massachusetts was creating the document.  Please ensure that your Reader is of the latest version.

Comment: It's just fine for me. Are you sure you've set to print it in colour? Do you get other files printed with the exact same settings?

Comment: Adobe Reader XI prints it in color for me. Chrome prints it in color for me as well. Are you filling out the form before you print it?

Comment: FYI, based on metadata, the PDF was produced with InDesign CC 2017 and is PDF version 1.7, Adobe Extension Level 3